# How to use IF or Case statement in Select Query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, if-statement, case

I am trying to get data from database with some case because on code level it is creating huge load on page.

I am using below query to do this:

```
Select * From users If user_status='active' and user_group=2 on case 'student' and user_group=3 on case 'teacher'
```

Please help me solve my issue if you have experience on mysql?

Comment: I suppose you need `where`. And what is `student/teacher`?

Comment: what is your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(user_status='active' and user_group=2, 'student', ''), IF(user_status='active' and user_group=3, 'teacher', '') FROM users
```